How does Paul use 'prasso' and 'poio' in Romans 7:15 and 7:19?
Romans 7:15 ESV [My brackets]

"For I do not understand my own actions. For I do not do [prasso] what I want, but I do [poio] the very thing I hate."

Romans 7:19 ESV [My brackets]

"For I do not do [poio] the good I want, but the evil I do not want is what I keep on doing [prasso]."

v15 do not do/prasso; do do/poio.
v19 do not do/poio; do do/prasso.
James Dunn in "Word Biblical Commentary. Romans 1-8"  p391, says with regard to v19-

"The verse repeats v15 but with  prasso and poio interchanged, [a further reminder of how generalised and unspecific Paul's language is.]"

I think Dunn's description of "unspecific" reduces Paul's use of Greek synonyms to an attempt to make his writing more colourful, to spice it up for the reader, rather than to convey truth. I do not think Paul's subject is so boring that it needs spicing up. Therefore I look for another explanation of how Paul uses these synonyms.

I think you have answered your own question - the two verbs' meaning overlaps significantly and their use here is synonymous.

@Dottard I have posted an answer to this question in which I try to show how these synonyms, though having some overlap in meaning with each other, yet retain differences wherein lie a wealth of meaning.

It’s a rhetorical device intended to help the reader grasp the structure of the text.  Grasping the structure is important because, for the author, form follows function; for the audience, function follows form.  The author designs the structure to trigger a flow of meaning; the audience comprehends meaning from that design (aka: commonly called ‘interpretation’).
The “flipping” of the verbs is a signal that at the beginning the author opened up (or started) a concept and then makes a point and then at the end closes down (or ends) the concept.  It signals Inclusio.
We see that here.  Though I think here it’s more likely a chiasm.  Here's the NASB20, formatted as a chiasm.
15 For I do not understand what I am doing;
   for I am not practicing what I want to do,
   but I do the very thing I hate. 
     16 However, if I do the very thing I do not want to do,
        I agree with the Law, that the Law is good. 
          17 But now, no longer am I the one doing it,

             but sin that dwells in me.

     18 For I know that good does not dwell in me, that is, in my flesh;
        for the willing is present in me,
        but the doing of the good is not. 
19 For the good that I want, I do not do,
   but I practice the very evil that I do not want.

20 But if I do the very thing I do not want,
   I am no longer the one doing it,

       but sin that dwells in me.

21 I find then the principle that evil is present in me,
   the one who wants to do good.

Notice how verse 20 restates the central point, made in verse 17.  (This is one reason I think it’s a chiasmus.)  And, that verses 20-21 are also a chasmus.  The central point is rhetorically quite loud.  Paul has, in effect, wrapped the concept of “indwelling sin” in a package of two things:  what he wants to do, and what he doesn’t want to do.  There’s a conundrum between the do and don’t do.  Paul’s leading the reader to arrive at the question:  What explains that conundrum?  The answer Paul then provides is:  Indwelling sin.  And so, he reiterates the central point:  sin dwells in me.
While I don't think accepting the full chiasmus structure is critical to the interpretation, the observation of start, finish, and central point is critical.
And that central point drives a key principle he wants the audience to know, which is the next verse.  If I may restate verse 21:

I find then this guiding principle:  I have the will to do good, but
evil is right there, ready at hand.

In other words, the two, good and evil, are inseparable in the human being.  He does not want his audience to miss this key point.  He’s quite explicit!
As an aside, but I think an important observation:  In should be observed that Paul uses παράκειμαι (to be present, to lie beside) in verse 18 and verse 21.  But, he flips the referent.  In 18 the referent is ‘good’ (through extension from ‘willing’).  In verse 21, the referent is ‘evil’.  For what it might be worth, I’ve wondered if παράκειμαι has connotations of intimacy.  But, the picture is that good and evil, in the human being, lie beside each other.
Lastly, In this overall section, 7:7-25, I believe Paul describes a Catch-22 situation.  To explain it would take us too far a field from the OP question  But, let me summarize the way I see it relating to the OP; it neatly ties this whole section together.  And it explains what Paul was attempting to do, and the fact that he couldn’t do it.
Paul coveted something.  This is what he wanted to do.  What did he covet?  I think it was righteousness.  And that very thing set up the Catch-22 situation.  If he didn’t pursue righteousness, then he wouldn’t obtain it.  If he did pursue righteousness, then it was covetousness (and if anyone tried hard to obtain righteousness, it was Paul).  He wanted to do the good, but, right there, inescapably, was the evil.  They lay right next to each other.  He’s damned if he does, he’s damned if he doesn’t.  He cries out, “Who can save me from the inevitable bodily death?”  The answer is, “someone who is righteous and dies in my place.”
There’s then no condemnation.

I love your breakdown of verses 15-21.  I have to disagree that Paul is saying "he's damned if he does or does not".  I see him saying more that 'he is incapable of doing what he wants to do (that which he would like to do)'.  The end result is the same, as you stated, Christ being our righteousness.  Our faith in Him and that promises no condemnation to us for our unrighteousness.  I do see Paul referring to literal sin that he chooses to do, rather than referring to attaining his own righteousness.  Nice answer all the same +1

@MarkVestal  So, it's covet it but couldn't achieve it.  Hmmmm...I'll have to think about that.  I came to the Catch-22 idea when it seemed to me that Paul was at a place of utter hopelessness (verse 24), like a Catch-22.  It wasn't, "well, maybe, just maybe, if I try just a little bit harder."  In any case, you bring up a good alternative.  Thanks!

It is important because of the hope it gives us as sinners who can't seem to escape our desire to sin (being trapped in this flesh). When a sinner is desperate to escape the entrapment, they discover hope learning that they will not be condemned by God if they place their faith in Christ BEING their unattainable righteousness. It truly frees us from the sin that we are trapped in. We then work FROM knowing this truth rather than FOR earning our righteousness. We are literally saved upon this understanding. 'Christ died for our sins, was buried, but rose again on day three for us' 1 Cor 15:1-4

In a nutshell, Paul is saying 'I do not want to be who I am carnally, therefore I thank God for giving me Jesus Christ, so that the spiritual person I am will not be condemned for my carnal failures in this physical life'.  2 Cor 5:21 "For he hath made him to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him."

@MarkVestal The other thing that sent me down the Catch-22 path was Paul's use of the word, ἐξαπατάω (deceive, trick, beguile), in verse 11.  I think of it as 'con'.  The main characteristic of a con is that the person being tricked thinks they are getting the benefit.  Sin used the Law (as in Paul's unrelenting pursuit of righteousness) to trick him into doing what he did not want to do.  That is, he most certainly did not want to break the law.  He was beguiled.  The Catch-22 idea explains the trickery.

I see your point and believe it fits.  Paul's unrelenting pursuit of righteousness would effectively be an unrelenting pursuit to stop the sin that he cannot stop.  But now, he can remember what God did for him through Jesus Christ being crucified (because of our inability to stop sinning on our own).  THAT is the power for Paul, and all of us, to use to overcome the sin that we struggle with.  So yes, believing that we can stop sinning on our own accord would be the con that Paul may be referring to.  Good conversation!

@MarkVestal  I've wondered about verse 24 (τίς με ῥύσεται ἐκ τοῦ σώματος τοῦ θανάτου τούτου;)  I've wondered if "body of death" has the term 'body' referring not to Paul's physical body, but to the 'real, almost physical, system' (if you will) that had tricked him.  The reason is ῥύομαι (rescue, deliver, draw to oneself) really does have the idea of "pulling toward oneself".  Well, that fits with the ἐκ (from) quite well. "Who will pull me out of this deadly system?"  He's drowning.  Your take or my take...both fit.  Yeah, great conversation.  :-)  Thanks for sharing.

I agree, and who controls the system? 2 Cor 4:1-4 "Therefore seeing we have this ministry, as we have received mercy, we faint not; 2 But have renounced the hidden things of dishonesty, not walking in craftiness, nor handling the word of God deceitfully; but by manifestation of the truth commending ourselves to every man's conscience in the sight of God. 3 But if our gospel be hid, it is hid to them that are lost:
4 In whom the god of this world hath blinded the minds of them which believe not, lest the light of the glorious gospel of Christ, who is the image of God, should shine unto them."

I didn't catch it before, but I think the way you stated verse 21 in your answer may be off, unless I'm misreading it.  It wouldn't be the evil in Paul that wants to do good.  It would be Paul that wants to do good, but he finds that evil is still present with him.

@MarkVestal Your conclusion is certainly true.  Are you referring to the formatted verses?  I think that threw me, too.  The 'one' refers to 'Paul', and not 'the evil'.  If you are to the preformatted text, that's right out of the NASB20.  I'll edit and make that clearer.

+1. I like this answer.  Many thanks.

Examples of "prasso":
From Romans 1:32  all ESV

"Though they know God's decree that those who practice such things deserve to die." [practice/prasso].

Here prasso is doing/practicing evil.
Romans 2:2

"We know that the judgement of God rightly falls on those who practice such things." [practice/prasso]

Practice such things. Such things are evil and condemn the perpetrators of them.
From Romans 2:5

"For circumcision  indeed is of value if you obey the law,"  [obey/prasses]

This is part of Paul saying that obeying/practicing the law will be incomplete, insubstantial, unsuccessful, [like building on sand], when attempted by those clinging to the law, as the way to righteousness.
Matthew 7:24-27 for "building on sand".
Examples of "poio":
From John 11:47

"For this man performs many signs." [performs/poiei]

Jesus doesn't need to "practice", He is perfect, He performs.
From Romans 9:20-21

"Why have you made me like this?" Has the potter no right over the clay,...".
[made/poiesas]

poio is substantial. When God makes something then that is what it is.
From John 3:20-21

"For everyone who does wicked things". does/prasson  wicked.


"But whoever does what is true..". does/poion true.

Back to Romans  7:15 and 7:19-
v15 The good I want to do I do not/prasso. I don't even get started let alone make a feeble first attempt. [Doesn't get violin out of case let alone practice/prasso it].
v19 The good I want to do I am emphatically not going to perform/poio [a step up from practice], as I said in v15 I don't even do it badly.
v15 Into the evil I do I put my best effort/performance/poio,
v19 but because it is evil, confused, I still achieve/prasso nothing substantial, lasting, it remains building on sand.
[I think Paul's use of synonyms is very precise. Paul is a skilled [Acts 22:3] servant [Ro 1:1] of
Jesus Christ our Lord].

I do not see how this answers the question - one cannot base an important conclusion upon so little data/evidence.  Many counter examples could be cited.

The illustration of not even getting the violin out of the case is fairly brilliant. Nice one!
